# Internal workings of mysql(i)_query and mysql(i)_fetch_*

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder how `mysql_query`/`mysqli_query` and `mysql_fetch_*`/`mysqli_fetch_*` functions really work. Where is result of `mysql_query` call stored? Is it MySQL server or PHP client? When the transmission of data occurs?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO anyways.

Comment: [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-query.php) returns an object, so I'd say the call is stored on the server.

Comment: Well, if you're really curious, you could dive in [PHP's source code](http://php.net/downloads.php). Look in the ext/mysql* directories.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cooperation between PHP and the MySQL server. `mysql*_query` sends a query to the server, which prompts it to sift through its data and assemble a result set. This result set now needs to be transferred over to PHP, one row at a time.

By default, `mysql*_query` uses a *buffered query*, which means it's transferring the data little by little over to PHP as soon as it can. When calling `mysql*_fetch*`, you read a row of this data one by one. You can also use *unbuffered queries*, e.g. using `mysql_unbuffered_query`. This does not transfer data in the background, it only does so when you explicitly call one of the `*fetch*` functions. This uses less memory on the PHP side, but is slower and in turn requires the SQL server to hold onto the data longer than it would have otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and revealing the terminology (_buffered/unbuffered_ queries)!